# Google share and Facebook sharer not pulling through information

Tags: facebook, iis, google-plus

I am running an MVC application on IIS.
when sharing a URL on either facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Ftn.hollaroo.com%2Fcontent%2Faux%2Fhollaroo%2Findex.html) or google+ (https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://tn.hollaroo.com/content/aux/hollaroo/index.html) it works with STATIC.html
When I am trying to do the same thing with tn.hollaroo.com/terms - no meta-data (title, description, image) is pulled through. index.html is a "view source + save as html" copy of /terms, so I doubt that the error is in the HTML itself.
Header section as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">

<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

<meta itemprop="name" content="Hollaroo Trusted Network">
<meta property="og:description" content="The Trusted Network ...">
<meta name="description" content="The Trusted Network ..." />
<meta property="og:title" content="Hollaroo Trusted Network" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://tn.hollaroo.com/content/aux/hollaroo/images/posting.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Hollaroo - Private Social Recruitment Networks" />
```

is all there.
I have run CURL and the main difference I spot there is that I am trying to set a cookie:

```
~# curl -I http://tn.hollaroo.com/terms
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 26085
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=wscxgkryniqa0qd3dmukjpxe; path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Fri, 07 Mar 2014 16:03:09 GMT

~# curl -I http://tn.hollaroo.com/content/aux/hollaroo/index.html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public
Content-Length: 26400
Content-Type: text/html
Last-Modified: Fri, 07 Mar 2014 15:44:21 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "e076f21b1c3acf1:0"
Date: Fri, 07 Mar 2014 16:03:32 GMT
```

The /terms url does not require login.
According to my IIS log AND to my own log in the app - I do get hits from facebook and I do return data:
IIS LOG:

2014-03-07 15:05:44.590 /terms - "D:\WEBS\Edge\terms" 200 "DEMO1" - 0 0 225
  2014-03-07 15:05:54.605 /terms fb_locale=en_GB "D:\WEBS\Edge\terms" 200 "DEMO1" - 0 0 267

```
  Url   UserId  IPAddress   Browser At
/terms  NULL    173.252.100.117 facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)   2014-03-07 15:05:44.263
/terms?fb_locale=en_GB  NULL    173.252.100.113 facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)   2014-03-07 15:05:54.387
```

I am not disallowing web crawlers or blocking fb's IP.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Have you tried using something like the [Facebook URL debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug‎) to see what Facebook sees?

Comment: yes, that was the starting point. facebook: Could not retrieve data from URL; google: The server at tn.hollaroo.com is taking too long to respond.

Comment: For what it's worth, it takes an unbelievable amount of time to connect to the server from my location. Google may have put it best with "is taking too long to respond".

Comment: Both Facebook's and Google's test fetchers just parsed it fine for me. There might have been a transient error where their servers couldn't access your server.